# MySQL Compare timestamps from two different tables and sort the latest record

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following query to get data from the tables. I want to sort the data based on timestamp from two different tables. Whichever timestamp is the latest one should be sorted as first record followed by the second and third etc. However, I see that this is partially working. It is sorting latest record but based on only one table `messages`. If a record is newer record comes in the `swipes` table then that one should come first which is not happening.

```
SELECT usr.id, usr.gender, usr.last_activity, CONCAT(usr.first_name, ' ', usr.last_name) as fullName FROM
(SELECT swp_to uid, created_at cat FROM swipes WHERE swp_from = :user AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
  UNION
  SELECT swp_from uid, created_at cat FROM swipes WHERE swp_to = :user AND first_swp IN ('like','superlike') AND second_swp IN ('like','superlike')
) u
LEFT JOIN messages m ON u.uid IN (m.msg_from, m.msg_to)
INNER JOIN users usr ON u.uid = usr.id
GROUP BY u.uid ORDER BY GREATEST(MAX(m.created_at), MAX(u.cat)) DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

I guess that the `GREATEST()` function is not working as expected. It is only sorting based on the latest messages which is about `MAX(m.created_at)` only. It feels like as if it is ignoring that `MAX(u.cat)` is also there to compare with. What mistake am I making here?

**UPDATE**

[SCREENSHOT FOR QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhhcK.png)

Comment: GREATEST() selects one value from MAX(m.created_at) and MAX(u.cat) for current group, and uses this value for sorting. *It feels like as if it is ignoring that MAX(u.cat) is also there to compare with.* If it is less than MAX(m.created_at) then of course it is not used.

Comment: @Akina I have checked throughout before posting the question. I have set `MAX(u.cat)` to be the latest and it is still not sorting as expected.

Comment: Add both `MAX(m.created_at)` and `MAX(u.cat)` and `GREATEST(MAX(m.created_at), MAX(u.cat))` expressions into the output list and try to find the row where the function selection is not correct by your opinion.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the hint. I think I found out why this is happening. I have added a screenshot. You can see that No.23 should be on top as it's `created_at` field in the `swipes` table is the latest. But since there is no record for No.23 in the `messages` it is not being able to compare as it returns null. I got the issue now but I still need a solution to fix. A solution for when there is no record in the `messages` table for a particular user but still it's timestamp for `created_at` in `swipes` is latest compared to those in the `messages` table of other users, it should be on the top.

Comment: Yes, both `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions returns NULL if at least one argument is NULL. You may use, for example, `GREATEST(COALESCE(value1, value2), COALESCE(value2, value1))` or `CASE WHEN value1 IS NULL THEN value2 WHEN value2 IS NULL THEN value1 ELSE GREATEST(value1, value2)` and so on..

Comment: @Akina Interesting, let me try both.

Comment: @Akina `COALESCE` worked. Thanks a lot. I didn't try `CASE` method here as `COALESCE` already returned correct result and is less coding. If this was an answer, I would have had accepted it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When any of arguments provided into GREATEST() function is NULL then the function returns NULL despite of another arguments values.

ORDER BY treates NULL value as the most least one.

You must provide correct greatest value selection which takes into account that a value can be NULL. For example, you may use

```sql
ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(MAX(m.created_at), MAX(u.cat)), 
                  COALESCE(MAX(u.cat), MAX(m.created_at))) DESC
```

In this case the expression will return NULL only when both values are NULL.